# Turn move number off in \variation

Tags: chess, xskak

Can we customize `\variation` command to suppress display of move numbers ? `\variation{1. e4}` should display `e4` (without the move number). Can this be done ?

I should have explained the problem more clearly. I'm talking about the `\variation` command which is part of `xskak` package, to display chess moves. I can customize the `\variation` command using `beforenumber`, `whiteopen`, `blackopen` etc. What ever I do, the final output displays the move number. Also, `\variation{e4}` is invalid as `\variation` command expects the move number. So, my question is, can we customize `\variation` command to not display the move number in the final output (along the lines of `beforenumber` etc).

Here's an MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xskak}

\begin{document}
\newchessgame\mainline{1. e4 e5} \variation{2. Nf3}
\end{document}
```

`\variation{Nf3}` is an invalid statement. But I do not want `2.` in the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a `\variationNM` command in the same vein as `\variation`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xskak}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\variationNM}[1][]{%
 \setkeys[UFXS]{print}{#1}%
 \begingroup\catcode`\#=12 \@variationNM}
\def\@variationNM#1{\endgroup
  \gdef\NumberNext{\False}%
  \gdef\AfterBlack{\False}%
  \gdef\PrintMoves{\False}%
  \gdef\ExecuteMoves{\False}%
  \gdef\StoreLastMove{\False}%
  {\variationstyle\opencommands%
   \variationmovemode
   \Mainline(#1 Z )%
   \closecommands}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\newchessgame\mainline{1. e4 e5} \variationNM{Nf3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yup. Thats exactly what i'm looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the usage can be a bit different, there is very simple solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\variation#1.{}

\variation1.e4
\variation11. e4-e5

\end{document}
```

That gives `e4` `e4-e5` etc., simply eating the number.

Otherwise the definition is more complicated:

```
\def\variation#1{\def\pomin##1.##2.{##2}\pomin#1.}
```

with the usage

```
\variation{12. e6}
\variation{13. e7}
```

and the desired result.

Comment: Although it works, This is not what I'm looking for. I've edited the question which explains the issue I'm facing.

Answer (score 0):

@Surya, here is an example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\title{xskak Dua Kolom}
\usepackage{xskak}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \textbf{Botvinnik -- Smyslov} \\
    \textit{World Championship Match (17)} \\
    \textit{Moscow 1957} \\
    Gr\"{u}nfeld Defence
\end{center}

\newchessgame
\xskakset{style=styleC}

\mainline{1. Nf3 Nf6 2. g3 g6 3. c4 c6 4. Bg2 Bg7 5. Nc3 O-O 6. d4 d5 7. cxd5
cxd5 8. Ne5 b6}
\[ \showboard \]
A satisfactory way of developing.  After {\variation[invar]{8... Nc6 9. Nxc6
bxc6}} Black would be saddled with a weak pawn at c6.

\mainline{9. Bg5 Bb7 10. Bxf6 Bxf6 11. O-O}

In the variation {\variation[invar]{11. e4 dxe4 12. Nxe4 Bxe5 13. dxe5 Nd7
14. f4 Nc5}} Black has a good game.

\mainline{11... e6 12. f4}

If {\variation[invar]{12. e4 Nc6 13. exd5} (\variation[invar]{13. Nxc6 Bxc6
14. exd5 exd5}) \variation[outvar]{13... Nxe5 14. dxe5 Bxe5 15. dxe6 Bxg2 16.
exf7+ Rxf7 17. Kxg2 Bxc3 18. bxc3 Qxd1 19. Rfxd1 Rc8 20. Rd3 Rc4}}, and Black
can successfully battle for a draw in the rook ending.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This does not suppress the variation numbers as requested.